# group by with outer/left join in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, group-by

I have data in 1 table as

```
UserID CourseID TestID   Result
1         1       1        P
1         1       2        P
2         1       1        F
2         1       2        F
```

this is showing that 2 Users ( UserID =1 and 2) has taken Test ( TestID=1 and 2) in CourseID =1

Now that CourseID in total has 3 Tests ( say TestID=1,2,7) as

```
CourseID TestID
1          1
1          2
1          7
```

this means none of the user has taken Test ( TestID=7) show now i want to show data as below

```
UserID CourseID TestID   Result
1         1       1        P
1         1       2        P
1         1       7        null
2         1       1        F
2         1       2        F
2         1       7        null
```

I have been trying with left/right outer join with Group by, but could not get the desired result. How it can be achieved?

Comment: its sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbe93/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Result
(
  UserID int,
  CourseID int,
  TestID int,
  Result char(1)
)
insert into Result values
(1,         1,       1,        'P'),
(1,         1,       2,        'P'),
(2,         1,       1,        'F'),
(2,         1,       2,        'F')

create table Course
(
  CourseID int,
  TestID int
)

insert into Course values
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 7)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select U.UserID,
       C.CourseID,
       C.TestID,
       R.Result
from (
     select distinct UserID
     from Result
     ) as U
  cross apply Course as  C
  left outer join Result as R
    on R.CourseID = C.CourseID and
       R.TestID = C.TestID and
       R.UserID = U.UserID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbe93/2/0)**:

```
| USERID | COURSEID | TESTID | RESULT |
---------------------------------------
|      1 |        1 |      1 |      P |
|      1 |        1 |      2 |      P |
|      1 |        1 |      7 | (null) |
|      2 |        1 |      1 |      F |
|      2 |        1 |      2 |      F |
|      2 |        1 |      7 | (null) |
```

Note: If you have a table `Users` you could replace the derived table

```
 (
 select distinct UserID
 from Result
 ) as U
```

with `Users as U` instead.

Comment: seems to be working as expected, just a point about the last line -
R.UserID = C.TestID should'nt be R.UserID = U.UserID ?

Comment: @user1509581 It should be U.UserID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uct.UserId, ct.CourseID, ct.TestID, uct.Result
FROM CourseTest ct
LEFT JOIN UserCourseTest uct ON uct.CourseID=ct.CourseID AND uct.TestID=ct.TestID
```

Comment: i have tried this before and its not showing the correct result, output in this case is -
UserID CourseID TestID   Result
1         1       1        P
1         1       2        P
2         1       1        F
2         1       2        F
null      1       7        null

is something like above

Comment: I see the issue, need to join with users table r "select distinct userid" derived table. About to go to bed, though.